# toggle ,show and hide not working

Tags: html, css

i used toggle to hide paragraph through a video but i do not run

```
<div class="site-slider">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                    <div class="overlay"></div>

                    <video id="video_background" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" volume="0" width="100%">

                        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Video not supported
                    </video>

                    <div class="slider-caption ">
                        <div class="hide">
                            <h2>Marketing Solutions Company</h2>
                            <p>feeling special</p>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="slider-btn" id="polina  onclick=" toggleContent()>Pause</a> </a>
                    </div>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.flexslider -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.slider -->
</div>
<!-- /.site-slider -->
</div>
```

how i can show this paragraph when i paused the video because i use display:none

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, so you should fix that before going any further.

Comment: And please correct your grammer, I can't even understand what you ment to say (And Im not native Speaker as well)

Comment: by Dusan: *You should also check your jquery links.* ( He wrote this as an answer)

Answer (score 0):

This Line Needs to be:

```
 <a href="#" class="slider-btn" id="polina"  onclick="toggleContent()">Pause</a>
```

There was one closing Tag to much and the `"?  was missing behind the onClick Event.

But there are several other invalid HTML Tags too.

- The `<source>` Tag doesn't gets closed for example.

If the code still does'nt work after correcting all HTML Markup please Post your Javascript Code as well.